# MySQL: Match a set of values to column values with a different order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a date and some fields with integer numbers like this:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers LIMIT 10;
```

| id | gen_date | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5 | n6 | n7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1990-12-27 | 22 | 43 | 18 | 23 | 16 | 7 | 0 |
| 2 | 1990-12-19 | 39 | 11 | 38 | 23 | 24 | 36 | 0 |
| 3 | 1990-12-12 | 44 | 12 | 10 | 48 | 14 | 4 | 0 |
| 4 | 1990-12-05 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 46 | 48 | 49 | 0 |
| 5 | 1991-12-25 | 10 | 2 | 44 | 49 | 29 | 34 | 0 |
| 6 | 1991-12-18 | 6 | 19 | 42 | 4 | 12 | 28 | 0 |
| 7 | 1991-12-11 | 1 | 12 | 42 | 7 | 31 | 25 | 0 |
| 8 | 1991-12-04 | 18 | 47 | 31 | 30 | 10 | 35 | 0 |
| 9 | 1991-11-27 | 38 | 33 | 39 | 47 | 13 | 11 | 0 |
| 10 | 1991-11-20 | 23 | 7 | 22 | 18 | 43 | 16 | 0 |

All row numbers are unique `nx <> ny`.

I want to match a set of 6 numbers against columns `n1 to n6` regardless or the value order.

For example, at row with `ID=1` there is `22, 43, 18, 23, 16, 7` and the row with `ID=10` has the same numbers `23, 7, 22, 18, 43, 16`. I have written a query to much every row containing all the numbers in a column set of each row. If I need to search for numbers `7, 16, 18, 22, 23, 43` then the result returns both rows `ID=1` and `ID=10`.

I got it working by using the `FIELD` function to search each number through all field values like this:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers
WHERE
 FIELD(7, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) > 0 AND 
 FIELD(16, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) > 0 AND 
 FIELD(18, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) > 0 AND 
 FIELD(22, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) > 0 AND 
 FIELD(23, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) > 0 AND 
 FIELD(43, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) > 0;
```

| id | gen_date | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5 | n6 | n7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1990-12-27 | 22 | 43 | 18 | 23 | 16 | 7 | 0 |
| 10 | 1991-11-20 | 23 | 7 | 22 | 18 | 43 | 16 | 0 |

This works, but I have some concerns about the way it works and if that approach is performance wise when using against tenths of thousands of rows.

Is there another better (*or maybe more simple*) way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: No, it is not too performant solution. But without normalising your datastructure, you are not going to find any performant ones. Sql is meant to search by columns, not by rows.

Comment: @Shadow thanks for the comment. I did not design this; it's a table to store the results of a lottery. I am trying to figure out how that could be normalized in some way that would be flexible. Now if I want to search for more than one numbers group in the same query, I have to write that ugly fields checking for every group which of course is not a nice and performant solution.

Comment: @Shadow I realize that I need to split those numbers data to a separate table and use a one-to-many approach to have each lottery entry. Then it will be much flexible and I will be able to join and order the numbers and do much simpler queries with all performance gains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM numbers
WHERE
 7 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) AND
 16 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) AND
 18 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) AND 
 22 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) AND 
 23 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) AND 
 43 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) ;
```

Comment: S' euxaristo Giorgo! Thanks for simplifying that. Sometimes my head gets stuck and I cannot think of these simple things. Maybe splitting the numbers to a separate table would be the best case here for performance boost and make things more "pretty". Will accept if I do not get other answers. +1

Comment: @ChristosLytras Parakalo Christo! I agree that normalizing the table is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Sum the rows, it will give you a more manageable recordset.

Because 4+5+8+9 = 9+4+5+8

So this gives you a smaller data set to manipulate.

Load each row into a linked list and sort from large to small, you can then compare the first element in the lists, removing the lists that don't match, until you've found the one that does.  It would be O(n).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).